# Output a default asset if one hasn't been specified

Tags: assets, image

I've looked at and tried a couple of solutions on here but struggling to apply them to my circumstance.

Below is my current code.  I would like a 'default' asset (image) to be used if one hasn't been specified by the admin.  This is so that the front end doesn't have gaps in the gallery.

```
<ul id="photListing">
{% cache %}
  {% for entry in craft.entries.section('people').find() %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
      <figure>
      {% for block in entry.basicProfileInfo %}
      {% set varBarrPic = block.mx_peoplePhoto.first() %}
        <img src="{{ varBarrPic.url }}" alt="">
          <figcaption><span>{{ block.mx_positionWithinBusiness }}</span> {{ entry.title }}</figcaption>
      {% endfor %}
      </figure>
    </a>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endcache %}
</ul>
```

I hope this is a simple solution.

Many thanks

Martin

Answer (score 1):

You can test if your `first()` method returns an asset model. 
And depending on that have different image URLs, the (transformed) asset's one or the URL of your placholder image.

```
{% set image = block.mx_peoplePhoto.first() %}
{% set imageUrl = image ? image.url('500x500') : url('images/_static/placeholder.jpg') %}

<img src="{{ imageUrl }}">
```

You could also consider to get that placeholder image from a [global set](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/globals).

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  Something very bizarre happening, it's only pulling through a replacement image for the most recently added entry??  All previous entries seem to be ignored.  I've cleared caches.

Answer (score 0):

I have a macro that I use for all images that falls back to our logo if an image is not supplied to it for whatever reason.

```
{% macro imageTransform(image, transform, caption, extraHTML) %}
{# Fallback to our logo if the image is null... #}
{% if not image|length %}
    {% set image = craft.assets.id('84').first() %}
{% endif %}
<img src="{{ image.getUrl( transform ) }}" width="{{ image.getWidth( transform ) }}" height="{{ image.getHeight( transform ) }}" title="{{ caption|default('') }}" alt="{{ caption|default('') }}"{% if extraHTML %} {{ extraHTML }}{% endif %}>    
{% endmacro %}
```

And here is  a sample use of it

```
{% for row in imagesTable %}
    <div class="gallery-block__item">
        {% set image = row.image.first() %}             
        {% set caption = row.caption %}
        {% set transform = 'fit500By500' %}
        {% set extraHTML = "class=gallery-block__item-image" %}
        {{ imageLib.imageTransform( image, transform, caption, extraHTML) }}
        <span class="gallery-block__caption">{{ row.caption }}</span>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

(Note the lack of quotes on the extraHTML BTW)